# How to display image selected on input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

Im trying to display the image selected, but I keep getting the following error:

> Not allowed to load local resource:

Any ideas why?

```
<input type='file' id='fileName' name='fileName' capture='user' accept='image/*'  onchange=\"document.getElementById('myImg').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])\">

<p><img src='#' id='myImg'></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in your onchange event, i tried the code and it works

```
onchange="document.getElementById('myImg').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zakariatantaoui/7s3vpwey/)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with [@tantoui zakaria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12865050/tantaoui-zakaria). It seems you tried to escape the double quotes with **a front slash (/)** His code works as expected!